# Failures on underside layers of a chip in IGBT power modules

Tags: semiconductors, failure, igbt, reliability, component-failure

Does somebody know how I can detect a layer of IGBT modules in which a thermal failure, e.g., voids, cracks, delaminations of solder joints, has taken place?
We know there is fatigue in both solder joints of wire-bond IGBT power modules, one joint is between chip and DBC and another joint is between DBC and baseplate. When operating IGBT module, how can I find which joint is degraded? Is there a specific technique to detect it in practice?

Comment: x-rays are often used to check for defects under BGA packages. But I don't think that would extend to your needs.

Comment: This is not an answer either, but shorted MOSFET's and IGBT's will have a gate voltage present if the drain has voltage. The insides have fused into a lump.

Comment: Is this a 3 phase module ? What are the symptoms? Do you know how to measure Rth?

Comment: @Felthry, [acoustic microscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_microscopy) too.

Comment: When you tried Google for [failure analysis IGBT], what did you find out? Vote to close as "too broad"

Comment: @AliChen Stewart We know there is fatigue in both solder joints of wire-bond IGBT power modules, one joint is between chip and DBC and another joint is between DBC and baseplate. When operating IGBT module, how can I find which joint is degraded? Is there a specific technique to detect it in practice?